# Redirecting domains in /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, google-chrome, dns, hosts-file, domain-name

In my /etc/hosts file, I have the following line:

`127.0.0.1    www.reddit.com`

When I open www.reddit.com in chrome, it still displays normally. When I open www.reddit.com in an a chrome incognito session, it redirects to localhost. I tried clearing the cache, and still get the same behavior. Why do my normal profile and incognito mode work differently?

Comment: Interesting observation. Note it's not the url that's redirecting, it's only the domain (a url includes a domain but also additional info like path and protocol). I expect that restarting Chrome will fix the problem and it must have to do with threads, memory caching and process isolation.

Comment: (Changed title to be more accurate). Restarting chrome doesn't help. Neither does restarting the machine =/

Comment: @ericsoderstrom: If you've solved this, post the solution as an 'answer' below. Don't put it in the question form.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in this case was that I had a specific extension (Data Saver) which resulted in chrome not using `/etc/hosts`.